# Drush command to show installed modules but not being used?

Tags: drush

In the process of developing a site I inevitably install modules thinking they are the ones I want but they are not. I am looking for drush command to find these modules to disable them and reduce my resource overhead. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

maybe something like [drush resource cleaner];

Comment: drush read-my-mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Drush has no way of knowing if a module might have some hook that is performing an active service for the site, even in the absence of any configuration information, so no, this feature is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Drush, but try the [Master](https://www.drupal.org/project/master) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides utilities for controlling the module status of all modules in the whole installation by a single [Drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush) command. The configuration is done by defining "master modules". "Master modules" are (in most cases) custom modules or features, that provide dependencies to all modules that are needed to run the site. In combination with [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and maybe some custom code and scripts the whole site configuration can be managed via that approach.